# How to check tag description on SE mobile app?

Tags: discussion

I suppose this question could belong on any meta site, but I'm in this one because recently I asked a SE:WB question and couldn't readily choose between two tags: [interstellar-travel] and [interstellar].
At the time, I didn't know which one fit my question more (if not both equally), because there doesn't seem to be a way to check the qualifiers of a tag on the mobile app (Android--latest SE version).

Does there exist a way to check a tag description on the mobile app?

I attempted to pull up the site in a (mobile Chrome) browser, but it was rather persistent in forcing the launch of the mobile app. No sequence of clicks I found could take me to the list of tags without launching the app, even in "desktop mode."
I should be using a laptop for asking questions, and often do as it's much easier to do proper research, take notes, and multitask on a computer, but the majority of my SE use is on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

The launching of the mobile app is a configuration, you probably set the app to open all links from Stack Exchange at some point. Even with the browser, though, there is no way to read the description of a tag without opening it in a separate tab.

We may suggest in the main Meta that tags receive an alt-text with the main description for them. That way you'd be able to learn about a tag by holding up on it until the menu appears.

Answer (score 0):

The way I get around such annoying app launches on Google Chrok is utilizing the simple feature of pressing down on a link and then tapping “Open in new tab.”